# Can you guess where I am?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

In the city that I‘m currently in,

> there is a former marketplace, where elderly are reading outdated information.
>
> there is a share of homeless citizens, wandering about.
>
> there is a nice cafe which serves tea, 
>   but consumers are quite quiet.
>
> there is a Seaman‘s mission.

Hint:

> The weather is pretty bad in winter, for me the sun don‘t shine.

Hint 2:

> The city is neither Barcelona (the first time that we met), nor was it Leningrad (with its circus clown). It is also not Albuquerque (the city on Route 66).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in

> London

The second hint refers to

> other songs about cities, Barcelona (Freddie Mercury) and Leningrad (Billy Joel), and presumably Route 66.

All the clues and the first hint are

> Lyrics from the song [Streets of London](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?lyrics=7949)

there is a former marketplace, where elderly are reading outdated information.

> Have you seen the old man in the closed down market ..... Yesterdays paper, telling yesterdays news

there is a share of homeless citizens, wandering about.

> Have you seen the old dear who walks the streets of London / Dirt in her hair and her clothes in rags

there is a nice cafe which serves tea, but consumers are quite quiet.

> And in the all night cafe at a quarter past eleven / Same old man sitting there on his own / Looking at the world over the rim of his teacup / And each tea lasts an hour and he wanders home alone

there is a Seaman‘s mission.

> Have you seen the old man outside the seaman's mission (that was the easiest bit to Google)

Hint 1: The weather is pretty bad in winter, for me the sun don‘t shine.

> So how can you tell me that you're lonely / And say for you that the sun don't shine

Comment: I thought that „the sun don’t shine“ with the grammatical error would give it away. Interesting that you solved it via the seaman‘s mission...

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty much

> Norway

Firstly the hint:

> the winters are pretty bad in norway.

there is a former marketplaces, where elderly are reading outdated information.

> Kaupang was a Norse term for market-place. Today, it is generally used as a name of the first town-like market-place in Norway, the Kaupang in Skiringssal, which is located in Tjølling near Larvik in Vestfold. Kaupang was an important merchant and craft center during the Viking period and as yet the first known Norwegian trading outpost.Source Wikipedia

there is a share of homeless citizens, wandering about.

> Not sure about this.

there is a nice cafe which serves tea, but consumers are quite quiet.

> Many nice cafe are there in norway which serve tea.

there is a Seaman‘s mission.

> The Mission to Seafarers is a Christian welfare charity serving merchant crews around the world. Formerly known as Seaman‘s mission which has strong ties to norway.

Comment: +1 for the effort and the nice thoughts, but a city is needed, not a country. Also, any state has nice cafes where tea is served, that wouldn’t be a good hint...  Same with the homeless people. I have added the tag lateral thinking. A bit of specific background knowledge is needed as well.